# Same sequence/same card even though i have shuffled the deck

Tags: c, function

I have allready shuffled my deck and dealt it out and that works. However, when im about to make the user enter his/her input in my program and get two cards dealt out, i get the same cards, this is not what I want, i want different cards for both players and i dont want them duplicated.
I can not see whats wrong with my code, spend some hours looking through it, but in my eyes i feel it should be fine.

Its when i call the function: `player1();`and from there i call `printcards(deck)` and here's where i have my problem.
Can any of you guys help me with a solution here so when i call my function `printcards(deck)`i get different kinds of cards without them duplicated.

Heres how my code looks completely: (Its the last function where my problem is).

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DIAMONDS 0
#define CLUBS 1
#define HEARTS 2
#define SPADES 3
#define COLOR_SIZE 13
#define NR_OF_SUITS 4
#define DECK_SIZE 52
#define JACK 11
#define QUEEN 12
#define KING 13
#define ACE 1

struct Card
{
    int suit;
    int value;
    int *sum;
};
int test(struct Card *cardDeck);
int player2(struct Card* deck);
int player1(struct Card* deck);
int printCards(struct Card *cardDeck);
void swapCards(struct Card *cardA, struct Card *cardB);
void shuffleCards(struct Card *cardDeck);

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    //struct Card deck[DECK_SIZE];      //Statiskt allokerad array
    struct Card * deck; //Dynamiskt allokerad array
    int index;
    int suit_index;
    int startAt = 0;

    deck = (struct Card *)malloc(sizeof(struct Card) * DECK_SIZE);
    for (suit_index = 0; suit_index < NR_OF_SUITS; suit_index++)    /* Initiera kortleken */
        for (index = 0; index < COLOR_SIZE; index++)
        {
            deck[suit_index*COLOR_SIZE + index].suit = suit_index;
            deck[suit_index*COLOR_SIZE + index].value = index;
        }

    shuffleCards(deck);
    printf("\n\n");
    startAt = printCards(deck, startAt); //player 1
    startAt = printCards(deck, startAt); //player 2
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int printCards(struct Card *cardDeck, int start_index)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = start_index; i < start_index + 2; i++)
    {
        switch (cardDeck[i].value + 1)
        {
        case ACE: printf("Ace ");
            cardDeck[i].value = 11;
            break;
        case JACK: printf("Jack ");
            cardDeck[i].value = 10;
            break;
        case QUEEN: printf("Queen");
            cardDeck[i].value = 10;
            break;
        case KING: printf("King ");
            cardDeck[i].value = 10;
            break;
        default: printf("%d ", cardDeck[i].value + 1);
            break;
        }

        printf("of ");
        switch (cardDeck[i].suit)
        {
        case DIAMONDS: printf("Diamonds ");
            break;
        case HEARTS: printf("Hearts ");
            break;
        case CLUBS: printf("Clubs ");
            break;
        case SPADES: printf("Spades ");
            break;
        default: printf("Something went wrong!! ");
            break;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return i;
}


void swapCards(struct Card * cardA, struct Card *cardB)
{
    struct Card temp;
    temp = *cardA;
    *cardA = *cardB;
    *cardB = temp;
}

void shuffleCards(struct Card *cardDeck)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)
        swapCards(&cardDeck[i], &cardDeck[rand() % 52]);
}
```

Comment: Since I was dealt a "1 of Hearts" I suggest you have an array of the rank names, such as `char *rank[]= {"Ace", "Two", "Three", ..., "King"};` and have ranks in the range `0..12`, rather than adjusting the ranks' value. If you need to refer to a specific rank, you can use `enum { ACE, TWO, THREE, ..., KING};` instead of defining each separately. Then you'll avoid any confusion between numeric value and rank.

Comment: Why all the pointers?

Comment: William, don't alter the question to include code provided by the answers. That was really confusing until I found out what you'd done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need a new structure

```
struct CardDeck  
{
   struct Card cards[52];
   int last_Index;
};
```

This can hold where in the deck you are, and will not use a global variable.

so :-

### Updated

Re-wrote the questions code so it compiles.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DIAMONDS 0
#define CLUBS 1
#define HEARTS 2
#define SPADES 3
#define COLOR_SIZE 13
#define NR_OF_SUITS 4
#define DECK_SIZE 52
#define JACK 11
#define QUEEN 12
#define KING 13
#define ACE 1
struct Card    /* <<<< Card needs to be before CardDeck */
{
    int suit;
    int value;
    int *sum;
};
struct CardDeck
{
    struct Card cards[52];
    int last_Index;
};




int test(struct Card *cardDeck);
int player2(struct Card* deck);
int player1(struct Card* deck);
int printCards(struct CardDeck *cardDeck);
void swapCards(struct Card *cardA, struct Card *cardB);
void shuffleCards(struct Card *cardDeck);

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    //struct Card deck[DECK_SIZE];      //Statiskt allokerad array
    struct CardDeck * deck; //Dynamiskt allokerad array
    int index;
    int suit_index;
    int startAt = 0;
      /* Changed deck to a CardDeck */
    deck = (struct CardDeck *)malloc(sizeof(struct CardDeck) );
    deck->last_Index = 0; /* << ensure the deck is full of cards */
    for (suit_index = 0; suit_index < NR_OF_SUITS; suit_index++)    /* Initiera kortleken */
        for (index = 0; index < COLOR_SIZE; index++)
        {
            deck->cards[suit_index*COLOR_SIZE + index].suit = suit_index;
            deck->cards[suit_index*COLOR_SIZE + index].value = index;
        }

    shuffleCards(deck->cards); /* shuffleCards can still shuffle the cards array */
    printf("\n\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int printCards(struct CardDeck *cardDeck) /* changed to CardDeck */
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = cardDeck->last_Index; i < cardDeck->last_Index + 2; i++)
    {
        switch (cardDeck->cards[i].value + 1)
        {
        case ACE: printf("Ace ");
            cardDeck->cards[i].value = 11;
            break;
        case JACK: printf("Jack ");
            cardDeck->cards[i].value = 10;
            break;
        case QUEEN: printf("Queen");
            cardDeck->cards[i].value = 10;
            break;
        case KING: printf("King ");
            cardDeck->cards[i].value = 10;
            break;
        default: printf("%d ", cardDeck->cards[i].value + 1);
            break;
        }

        printf("of ");
        switch (cardDeck->cards[i].suit)
        {
        case DIAMONDS: printf("Diamonds ");
            break;
        case HEARTS: printf("Hearts ");
            break;
        case CLUBS: printf("Clubs ");
            break;
        case SPADES: printf("Spades ");
            break;
        default: printf("Something went wrong!! ");
            break;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    cardDeck->last_Index += 2; /* original post had this increment - ensures each time this is called, 2 cards get used */
    return i;
}


void swapCards(struct Card * cardA, struct Card *cardB)
{
    struct Card temp;
    temp = *cardA;
    *cardA = *cardB;
    *cardB = temp;
}

void shuffleCards(struct Card *cardDeck)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)
        swapCards(&cardDeck[i], &cardDeck[rand() % 52]);
}
```

Comment: I've tried it your way, but i dont get it. When i Use your code and use my switch statement it doesnt really work.
Can you edit your code and try to use mine to sum it up in a solution because im confused when im entering my own code in your ".....".
Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, look at my code above, i've tried to edit it like you did, but still. It wont work at all. Could you please look it over again?

Comment: Great!
So before i accept your answer, do you just mind explaining the line of code:  deck->last_Index = 0;  And also shuffleCards(deck->cards);, why dont you just need to use shuffleCards(deck)?  

I so appreciate your help!

Comment: One more question, the function printcards()

Why do you use cardDeck->last_Index += 2?
I mean, why the += 2?

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't [cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

The reason why your code returns always the same cards is cause in both cases (Player1 and Player2) you're accesing the same indices in the deck:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    switch(cardDeck[i].value){
    ...
```

You should store the last index you took from the deck:

```
int last_index = 0; //Global variable    


void printCards(struct Card *cardDeck)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = last_index; i < last_index+2; i++)
    {
        switch (cardDeck[i].value + 1)
        ...
    }
    last_index += 2;
}
```

Without global variable:

```
void printCards(struct Card *cardDeck, int start_index)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = start_index; i < last_index+2; i++)
    {
        switch (cardDeck[i].value + 1)
        ....
    }
    return i;
}
```

And call it:

```
int startAt = 0;
startAt = printCards(deck, startAt); //player 1
startAt = printCards(deck, startAt); //player 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Well i dont want to use any global variables, so how should i do that then?

Comment: I really think the best is to use the global... But if you don't want, other options could be to supply `printCards` with the starting index (It could be stored in a player struct). Anyway, I think you're trying to do a blackjack game right? If that's so the global is the only solution (Think the case when player 1 takes 2 extra cards and the player 2 only one)

Comment: @Williamhart Edited my answer without the global, but just saw mksteve answers and I think it's more consistent than mine in case you don't want globals

Comment: I have edited my post like you told me to, but the code is still not working properly? Can you look it through again and tell me whats the matter?

I appreciate it!